# Installing Flight Simulator bricked my pc

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios, amd-ryzen

I've been trying to install the new Microsoft Flight Simulator and each time, it would get about half way through and the screen would go black and not respond to input but the fans were still all spinnning. Each time I was able to power cycle the machine and it booted up.

Its just happened again except now it won't boot up and just enters the same state - nothing on the screen, no error beeps, fans spinning but nothing happening.

*** Specs ***
[image: specs]

**What I've tried***

- Disconnecting external devices
- Removing the GPU and plugging the monitor into the built in hdmi port.
- Removed cmos battery to reset cmos

None of these things helped. Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: You have other problems having nothing to do with the installation of a game.  A user mode application (like flight simulator or its installer) simply CAN'T do this.  I know what you are thinking.. but I am telling you CANT.  If the machine won't even post now (aka no screen or beeps) you will need to follow the motherboard methods for troubleshooting "my machine wont post" (or similar).  Bummer dude.

Comment: Most likely a weak hardware component broke down because of the load created by that installation. I suggest a repair-shop.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something similar but not quite as extreme - I installed flight simulator and the next day my PC was extremely slow to start up, the task manager crashed every time I tried to run it, basically everything other than a web browser couldn't start, etc.

I deleted the entire flight simulator folder in:

```
> C:\Users\<my username>\AppData\Roaming
```

and once it finished deleting my PC went 100% back to normal.

(note that to find this folder you may need to search for "%appdata%" since it seems Windows tries to hide this folder)

I then ran mdsched.exe to check for hardware issues and nothing came up, so there must have been something in that folder that was somehow causing issues.

Hopefully this helps any future fellow googlers